# Why requests are not being processed concurrently?

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, webforms

I was testing concurrent requests with this code in a test page:

**aspx markup:**

```
Request arrived: <asp:Label ID="lblRequestArrived" runat="server" /> <br/>
Request completed: <asp:Label ID="lblRequestCompleted" runat="server" /> <br/>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblRequestArrived.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    lblRequestCompleted.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```

I opened 3 tabs in my browser, pasted the url in all tabs, and then made the requests quickly (one by one). I found these outputs:

*tab1*

```
Request arrived: 10:02:42 AM
Request completed: 10:02:47 AM
```

*tab2*

```
Request arrived: 10:02:47 AM
Request completed: 10:02:52 AM
```

*tab3*

```
Request arrived: 10:02:52 AM
Request completed: 10:02:57 AM
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why these requests are being serialized? How can I make these concurrent?

[I have tested it publishing on IIS too (release mode; with `EnableSessionState = "False"` in the page).]

**Update:**
I tried opening that page in 3 different browsers. But, this time it seems to work concurrently. Now, what does that mean? Anything related to *SessionState* ? But I have that disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer here:
[Simultaneous requests to a HTTP Handler not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985604/simultaneous-requests-to-a-http-handler-not-working)

> it's nothing to do with the web server or the application but merely
>   to do with browser behaviours. It seems that if you open several tabs
>   and navigate to the same URL in a browser like Firefox or Chrome the
>   browser makes the requests sequentially i.e. it waits for one to
>   finish before making the next. Opening two browsers and making the two
>   requests results in the expected behaviour